# Android: Determining number of cameras on 2.2 and above

Tags: android, camera

My app needs to run on Android 2.2 and above. I need a way to determine the number of cameras available. There are a number of posts addressing this but I couldn't find one that works.

One solution is simply to detect the OS version and anything with 2.2 would only be limited to 1 camera (even if the device really did have 2) but I still have no way of figuring out the number of cameras for any versions greater than 2.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple cameras are not supported on earlier OS versions, so you can just assume you have 1. even the device had 2, they are not supported by the standard Android API. For newer OS versions, just use the `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` and `Camera.getCameraInfo()` with an API level guard statement:

```
 int numCameras = 1;
 if (Build.Version.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
   numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
 }
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but it isn't clear to me how you can use getNumberOfCameras / getCameraInfo when those methods are not available in 2.2. Is there a way to use API 9 or greater on a device running 2.2 and detect when it's greater than 8? Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Nothing special really, the regular way of using newer APIs, see updated answer.

Comment: Ok, but do I have to do something in my AndroidManifest.xml? Currently I have minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="8". Do I have to set targetSdkVersion to something higher than 8 and/or minSdkVersion as well?

Comment: You have to compile your project with an SDK that has the APIs you need. It is generally a good idea to use the latest (17 for 4.2, ATM). Set `targetSdkVersion` to the highest version you want to support. Behaviour changes resulting from this are listed here for each version: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: More about this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: This approach is deprecated in API 21. Instead one should use  `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html