# What parameter need to be specified in place of device? Which is used in the video capture class

Tags: android, opencv, video, camera, device

```
public VideoCapture(int device)
 VideoCapture constructors.

Note: In C API, when you finished working with video, release CvCapture structure with cvReleaseCapture(), or use Ptr that calls cvReleaseCapture() automatically in the destructor.

Parameters:
device - id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index). If there is a single camera connected, just pass 0.
```

What parameter should i need to pass in place of device, to get the camera input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [more than one camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052037/android-determining-number-of-cameras-on-2-2-and-above), you can use index 0 or 1 (there are no Android devices with more cameras than 2). Otherwise, the index must be 0. It could be facing back, or front.

Comment: I asked about external camera device connected through USB cable.Hence, for that we need to specify parameter. So, what need to be specified in device spot?

Comment: See [discussion](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5826/uvc-camera-and-opencv-243-for-android-42/) on OpenCV forum. If the external camera gets connected to the system camera stack, and can be used with normal Java API, then you give to `videoCapture` the came **cameraId** as used in [Camera.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int))

Comment: If the external camera is available through special SDK, or gets connected to V4L as `/dev/video0`, you cannot use `VideoCapture` class as is; code modification is needed.